# Web view para android inferior a 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Aunque me funciona bien el WebView en general, en el que he habilitado javascript, al entrar en páginas que requieren más recursos, estas no se cargan (o se cargan mal) en móviles con versiones de android de 5 o menos. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de que funcione independientemente de la versión o si, por el contrario, debo buscar otra alternativa para que funcione en todas las versiones.

Código para el webView:

```
 /**
     * Método para la creación de la WebView, en la que se mostrará el enlace en el que el usuario deberá introducir el ID
     */
    public void CrearWeb ()
    {
        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webV);

        //Habilitar JavaScript
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(etiqueta);
    }

    /**
     * Método para abrir el player sin salir de la aplicación
     */
    public void Seguirweb ()
    {
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
        web.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if (web.canGoBack())
                            {
                                web.goBack();
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Estas compilando contra la última versión de Android?

Comment: Pepito agregabtu build.gradle